# front end SQL query from two tables giving zero results

Tags: sql, oracle

I could use some help building a query that will be used for KPI's. This the current setup and what I'm trying to achieve, FYI I am beginner at SQL but I need to pull total number of hours for specific EVT_PPM by given year. This is being done on the front end and I have not been able to get an inner join to work. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Table R5EVENTS:

```
  EVT_TARGET  EVT_CODE      EVT_PPM       EVT_STATUS     EVT_CLASS
   3/1/2019      1           PM-01           C              CM
   4/1/2019      2           PM-02           CANC           PC
   5/1/2019      3           PM-03           R              CM
```

Table R5BOOKEDHOURS:

```
BOO_EVENT     BOO_HOURS     
   1             2            
   2             5             
   3             1
```

My query

```
SELECT COUNT (1) boo_hours
FROM R5EVENTS, R5BOOKEDHOURS
WHERE (EVT_TARGET >= to_date('1/1/2019' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')  
AND
       EVT_TARGET <= to_date('12/31/2020' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')  )
AND
(EVT_PPM IN ('PM-01','PM-02','PM-03','PM-04','PM-05','PM-06','PM-06','ST-01','ST-02') )
AND EVT_STATUS != 'CANC'
AND EVT_CLASS LIKE 'CM'
```

The output I get is 0 results!

Comment: @MrMiygai . . . "frontend" is not a database.  Please tag with the database you are using.  Last learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: This article may help you out :
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: What type is `EVT_TARGET`?

Comment: If `evt_target` is a string, `EVT_TARGET >= to_date('1/1/2019' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')` is comparing a string with a date. And a string which does not convert easily to a date. It will either error, or not give the result you're expecting. It should be `to_date(evt_target, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= to_date('1/1/2019' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')`. Better yet, `evt_target` should be a [`date`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413).

Comment: @ajinkya I have not been able to get INNER JOIN to work this is being done on front end through a web application

Comment: @Schwern EVT_TARGET is a date field "schedule start date"

Comment: [Works For Me™](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b64053de8ee3bebfd5ce265e5b666932) in that it gives a non-zero result. Can you point out where it might be different?